# How to do a compressed differential archive in .NET?

Tags: .net, compression

I have byte arrays that can be a few dozen megabytes in size.  Such large arrays are not happy creatures, especially when you have a many of them.  So I would like to compress them, so they're easier to deal with.  They compress well, generally a 3:1 ratio with DotNetZip set to BestSpeed.

The data in the arrays can be nearly identical.  With this consideration, I was hoping to find some way to programmatically compress the arrays differentially, much like version control or backup software.  This way, if I have three arrays of 30 MB that differ only in sparse places, my zip file would be closer to 10 MB instead of 30.

I have tried many queries on google and stackoverflow, with language like compressed, archival, backup, diff, differential...none of my terms are turning up anything useful.  What should I be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look unto how the [`rsync`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) protocol works on Unix. It essentially computes the differences between two files and uses that to create a compressed delta used to compute the changes.

You may be able to adapt that to what you're trying to do.